# Ping a network using threads and testing it

Tags: python, testing, multithreading, ping

I am trying to ping two different networks with thread. I am able to get the response I want but I want to convert it into a test. I have the code that I have tried below but the test runner says that no tests were run. The code is below:

```
#!/home/workspace/downloads/Python-2.6.4/python
from threading import Thread 
import subprocess, unittest
from Queue import Queue 


class TestPing(unittest.TestCase):
    num_threads = 4 
    queue = Queue() 
    ips = ["10.51.54.100", "10.51.54.122"] 
    #wraps system ping command 
    def RunTest(i, q): 
        """Pings subnet""" 
        while True: 
            ip = q.get() 
            print "Thread %s: Pinging %s" % (i, ip) 
            ret = subprocess.call("ping -c 1 %s" % ip, 
                            shell=True, 
                            stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), 
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
            if ret == 0: 
                print "%s: is alive" % ip
                assert True 
            else: 
                print "%s: did not respond" % ip 
                assert False
            q.task_done() 
        #Spawn thread pool 
        for i in range(num_threads): 

            worker = Thread(target=pinger, args=(i, queue)) 
            worker.setDaemon(True) 
            worker.start() 
            #Place work in queue 
        for ip in ips: 
            queue.put(ip) 
        #Wait until worker threads are done to exit     
            queue.join()


class PingTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):

    def makePingTestSuite():
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(TestPingMove("TestPing"))
        return suite

    def suite():
        return unittest.makeSuite(TestPing)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I want the test to assert either true and false if a network gives no response and to run two tests for the 2 networks to be pinged. Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Just a nit: you can't ping "a network". You ping *hosts*, not entire networks. Unless you're doing a broadcast ping of course, which involves counting responses and stuff that you're clearly not doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subclass `unittest.TestCase`, all methods whose name begins with `test`, get run automatically. Otherwise, the code is not run as a test. (So `RunTest` is not getting run).

So if you change `RunTest` to (the not so mellifluous) `test_RunTest`:

```
class TestPing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_RunTest(self):
         add code here
```

then the code will run. Also note, that unittest expects `test_RunTest`'s first and only argument to be `self`.

If you want to test that `func(args)` raises an error, then use `self.assertRaises` like this:

```
self.assertRaises(AssertionError, func, args)
```

Or, if `func` returns `True` or `False`, then you can tests that the proper value is returned by using `self.assertTrue` or `self.assertFalse`.

Also, when you write unit tests, it would be wise to place all your functions/classes in a module, import the module for the unittest script, and then test that the functions are returning or raising what you expect in the unittest script. I could be wrong, but it seems as though at the moment you have the two pieces mixed together.